# how do you enable ssl using laravel 8 sail

Tags: laravel, docker, ssl, laravel-8, laravel-sail

I just created a new Laravel 8 project, following the instructions [in their docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#getting-started-on-macos). Using [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail) I have the site running locally on my machine just fine using `sail up`. I have set up an entry in `/etc/hosts` so the url I go to is `http://local.dev.domain.com` (substituting `domain.com` for the actual domain name I own, and pointing to `localhost` in the `/etc/hosts` file)...all works great.

However, the site needs to use Facebook Login, and Facebook requires https urls only on referrers. I've tried everything I could find online about setting up SSL certs with docker, but setting up nginx with manually created certs (via `mkcert`) or trying to use letsencrypt all fails for various reasons (conflicts in ports, letsencrypting wanting the domain to be a real one (and failing on the acme challenge if I do create that subdomain), etc. I've copied the certs to `/etc/ssl/certs` in the docker image and run `update-ca-certificates`, tried setting the application port `443` in my `.env` file as well as opening both ports `80` and `443` in the `docker-compose.yml` file...but all ends in the browser rejecting the request to `https://local.dev.domain.com`

I've spent hours trying to get this to work but it doesn't seem like anyone has used the Laravel Sail docker image with SSL.

Any pointers?

[Edit for more info]
As pointed out in the comments, you need to set an alias to just use `sail ...`, but I've already done that:

[image]

I also tried without the bash alias using `vendor/bin/sail share` to no avail:

[image]

Comment: try this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#sharing-your-site

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Problem

In your case you need a real domain, which you have. A self-signed certificate would not work as Facebook would not acknowledge it as trusted. To get a free ssl certificate for that domain you can use Let's Encrypt, the easiest way to obtain that certificate is using certbot. The problem is that you need to install that certificate on your webserver. Laravel Sail [uses the build-in webserver](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.0/supervisord.conf) that does not support ssl unfortunatly. You need to put a webserver like nginx in front of the app and [install the certificate there](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-nginx.html).

I'm currently working on [a fork](https://github.com/thomasmoors/spinnaker) that enables what you need, however it's not finished.

## Workaround

For now you can use the build in tunnel provided by Expose: https://beyondco.de/docs/expose/server/ssl

This is enable by `sail share`

It might be easier to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) instead, which is essentialy the same but commercial. Than all you have to do is download, register and run `ngrok http --region=eu 9000` and it will create a https link for you for development.

[image]

Comment: This is super useful, thank you! I'll keep an on your fork, sounds really promising! I've tried using `sail share` but I get an error saying it's not a valid command...

Comment: @smenzer You need to install sail properly to use this short alias: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#configuring-a-bash-alias otherwise you need `vendor/bin/sail share`

Comment: I did what you mentioned (updated the description with details) but it still didn't work to do `vendor/bin/sail share`

Comment: @smenzer maybe it's not possible on windows. However I suggest skipping that part and using ngrok for now.

Comment: I'm on a mac. but i'm trying to use ngrok now. I had to change the application port in .env to 9000 and then it seems to work and give me https access. Just need to work out the integration with facebook. looking forward to your project being ready!

Comment: @smenzer I missed that the docker container changes the port to 80 instead of the usual port 9000 when running `php artisan serve`

Comment: @onlineThomas an extra thump up for the fork you are working on! sounds great!

Comment: @smenzer I just saw this on another post. Apparently the version of sail you get by default isn't the latest, you need to use `composer require laravel/sail --dev` found in comments on here https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-8/episodes/12

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by using [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/) as a reverse proxy to the Laravel Sail container. Caddy has a feature called [automatic HTTPS](https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https) which can generate local certificates on the fly.

1 - Add Caddy as a service to your `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
    caddy:
        image: caddy:latest
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - '80:80'
            - '443:443'
        volumes:
            - './docker/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile'
            - sailcaddy:/data
            - sailcaddy:/config
        networks:
            - sail
            
    # Remove "ports" from laravel.test service
            
volumes:
    sailcaddy:
        driver: local
```

2 - Create a simple `Caddyfile` and configure it as a reverse proxy

```
{
    on_demand_tls {
        ask http://laravel.test/caddy-check
    }
    local_certs
}

:443 {
    tls internal {
        on_demand
    }

    reverse_proxy laravel.test {
        header_up Host {host}
        header_up X-Real-IP {remote}
        header_up X-Forwarded-For {remote}
        header_up X-Forwarded-Port {server_port}
        header_up X-Forwarded-Proto {scheme}

        health_timeout 5s
    }
}
```

3 - Set up an endpoint for Caddy to authorise which domains it generates certificates for

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Store;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CaddyController extends Controller
{
    public function check(Request $request)
    {
        $authorizedDomains = [
            'laravel.test',
            'www.laravel.test',
            // Add subdomains here
        ];

        if (in_array($request->query('domain'), $authorizedDomains)) {
            return response('Domain Authorized');
        }

        // Abort if there's no 200 response returned above
        abort(503);
    }
}
```

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gilbitron/36d48eb751875bebdf43da0a91c9faec) for the full code changes involved. [This blog post](https://gilbitron.me/blog/enabling-https-ssl-for-laravel-sail-using-caddy) explains how to trust the Caddy root certificates.

Comment: This looks really promising! I'm wondering if I'm missing anything; setting up the above with a fresh install (via `curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash`) and adjusting `laravel.test` to `example-app.test` then trying to reach `example-app.test` returns "This site can’t provide a secure connection \ example-app.test sent an invalid response. \ ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" in Chrome, and similar errors in Safari/FF. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean you changed `laravel.test` in your `docker-compose.yml`? If so, I don't think you can change `laravel.test` as I think Sail uses it internally. But you can update your hosts file to use whatever local domain you want. You might also want to check the logs for the caddy service to see what it's doing.

Comment: Ah interesting! Yeah the Caddy service logs showed it running, but not even acknowledging a request when I made one in the browser. I'll try again w/ `laravel.test`. Cheers!

Comment: I did as you said even the domain in the hosts file to `laravel.test` but I still get `This site can’t provide a secure connection laravel.test sent an invalid response.` in chrome browser

Comment: This is neat and it's working! How can we make Laravel Mix webpack devserver also reverse proxy React Fast Refresh or HRM on a different port? For example `http://localhost:8081`.

Comment: I did all of this, installed the rootCA by copying it to /etc/local/share/ca-certificates and running `sudo update-ca-certificates` (I'm on Ubuntu). However when visiting https://laravel.test chrome still throws NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. Any ideas? It seems the Expires On date equals the Issued On date...

Comment: For those having trouble with installing the rootCA and Chrome still throwing NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID: export the Caddy rootCA certificate and import it into chrome using its settings (chrome://settings/certificates). So do `sudo docker cp your-caddy-container-name:/config/caddy/pki/authorities/local/root.crt ~/Downloads/caddy-root.crt` (maybe you have to do `sudo chown your-user:your-user ~/Downloads/caddy-root.crt`). And then import that exported certificate as an "Authority" in the chrome settings (check all the boxes). DO NOT DO THIS WITH ANY OTHER CERTS!

Comment: I've been trying to get this solution working for days. The setup is simple enough, but Caddy can't verify the domains because it creates a redirect loop. Caddy sends a request to `http://laravel.test/caddy-check`, which it then redirects to `https://laravel.test/caddy-check` causing the request to fail with the error `following http redirects is not allowed`. Since there doesn't seem to be a way to exclude that single endpoint, the whole solution is a wash.

Answer (score 2):

For make "sail share" work you have to set alias and run "composer require laravel/sail --dev" on your project. This will install the latest version of sail,  version 0.0.6 includes "share" command

Comment: that did the trick. strange that the documented way of starting a laravel project (`curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash` from https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#getting-started-on-macos) doesn't include this by default

Comment: Sail is an optional development environment, like Laragon or Valet etc.

Comment: Just a note that Sail is included by default when using the online builder now. If you want to deep dive into the configs you can use `artisan publish:sail`.

Answer (score -1):

There is actually an easier way. I did the following:

changed laravel.test port to something else like 8085
do it from .env so u will avoid issues, add APP_PORT env var

then (this step has been done by our sys admin) since laravel sail is actually installing apache in the system, u can manually set a reverse proxy for both port 80 and 443 to port 8085 and that should do the trick.

of course u will have to install certbot on that apache instance.