# Laravel Sail use with HTTPS

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail

I wanna test my Laravel Sail Docker project with HTTPS enabled. How can I achieve this?

I thought `share` made this possible, but that is not correct.

```
▶ sail share --subdomain=foobar
Thank you for using expose.
Local-URL:      host.docker.internal:82
Dashboard-URL:      http://127.0.0.1:4040
Expose-URL:     http://foobar.laravel-sail.site:8080
```

I need to run my application on `https://`, but only get it working with http.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65302372/how-do-you-enable-ssl-using-laravel-8-sail

Answer (score 0):

You can only use HTTP, they (Laravel) don't configure HTTPS. You can read it [here](https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/216)

PS: I switched to ngrok and add this to `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` and it worked perfect:

```
public function boot()
{
    // Fix https
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
        $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
    }
}
```

I used the solution from [Ayman Elmalah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72335405/sharing-laravel-9-with-ngrok-cause-wrong-urls-to-be-generated).

Comment: In Laravel Homestead it is possible to use HTTPS, because Homestead comes with a .crt file, which you can import in your browsers (I successfully have imported it in Firefox, Chrome, Safari). Probably, in Laravel Sail that should be possible as well

Comment: It's possible to have https with Laravel Valet, but that doesn't use Docker. A bit frustrating. Hmm.