# Sharing laravel 9 with ngrok cause wrong urls to be generated

Tags: laravel, docker, ngrok

I am building a Laravel 9 project using docker desktop on windows.

So I was trying to share my laravel project with ngrok however my css and images are not loading since laravel generates asset urls with the http prefix when I am accessing a https link given by the ngrok.

I am running my laravel 9 project with
`sail up -d` and my ngrok with `ngrok http 80`.

I am able to access the site with the ngrok link but as mentioned no css and images are loaded since they are being access with an http link.

Comment: How are you asking for the assets? Are you using `asset`, `url` or `mix` helper?

Comment: yes I am using helpers to access them.

Comment: But which ones and how, show an example please...

Comment: I am using asset('css/design.css')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force app to use https in serving asset files when the server is using https

In `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
    {
        // Fix https
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
            $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
        }
    }
```