# Laravel Sail + Caddy - local dev site not trusted

Tags: docker, caddy, caddyfile

First time using `Docker + Sail + Caddy`. I copied the `Caddy` setup [from here](https://dev.to/adrianmejias/how-to-enable-ssl-for-local-development-using-laravel-sail-and-docker-51ee). I have a local `Laravel` dev project which uses 2x subdomains (sd1.project.local, sd2.project.local).

Everything looks fine on `sail up`. I can see the certs created in the expected local stores, one for each subdomain. I then import the two certs to `Chrome`.

I can get to the site, though `Chrome` does not trust it. I have restarted `Chrome` after the cert imports.

What have I missed / messed? Thanks!

The error of `curl -vvv` on `sd1.project.local` is:

```
$ curl -vvv https://sd1.project.local

*   Trying 127.0.0.1:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to sd1.project.local (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

The output of the `sail up` command for `caddy` is:

```
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"info","ts":1651470513.5381901,"msg":"using provided configuration","config_file":"/etc/caddy/Caddyfile","config_adapter":"caddyfile"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"warn","ts":1651470513.5383825,"logger":"caddyfile","msg":"Unnecessary header_up X-Forwarded-Host: the reverse proxy's default behavior is to pass headers to the upstream"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"warn","ts":1651470513.5384026,"logger":"caddyfile","msg":"Unnecessary header_up X-Forwarded-For: the reverse proxy's default behavior is to pass headers to the upstream"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"warn","ts":1651470513.5386436,"logger":"caddyfile","msg":"Unnecessary header_up X-Forwarded-Host: the reverse proxy's default behavior is to pass headers to the upstream"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"warn","ts":1651470513.5386622,"logger":"caddyfile","msg":"Unnecessary header_up X-Forwarded-For: the reverse proxy's default behavior is to pass headers to the upstream"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"warn","ts":1651470513.5391574,"msg":"Caddyfile input is not formatted; run the 'caddy fmt' command to fix inconsistencies","adapter":"caddyfile","file":"/etc/caddy/Caddyfile","line":2}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"warn","ts":1651470513.5395052,"logger":"admin","msg":"admin endpoint disabled"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"info","ts":1651470513.5397356,"logger":"tls.cache.maintenance","msg":"started background certificate maintenance","cache":"0xc0001264d0"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"info","ts":1651470513.5441852,"logger":"http","msg":"enabling automatic HTTP->HTTPS redirects","server_name":"srv0"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"warn","ts":1651470513.5442154,"logger":"http","msg":"server is listening only on the HTTP port, so no automatic HTTPS will be applied to this server","server_name":"srv1","http_port":80}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"info","ts":1651470513.5448365,"logger":"tls","msg":"cleaning storage unit","description":"FileStorage:/data/caddy"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"info","ts":1651470513.544853,"logger":"http","msg":"enabling automatic TLS certificate management","domains":["sd1.project.local","sd2.project.local"]}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"info","ts":1651470513.545812,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"acquiring lock","identifier":"sd1.project.local"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"info","ts":1651470513.5458567,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"acquiring lock","identifier":"sd2.project.local"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"info","ts":1651470513.5476136,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"lock acquired","identifier":"sd1.project.local"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"info","ts":1651470513.5479813,"logger":"tls","msg":"finished cleaning storage units"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"info","ts":1651470513.5485632,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"lock acquired","identifier":"sd2.project.local"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"info","ts":1651470513.5563135,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"certificate obtained successfully","identifier":"sd1.project.local"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"info","ts":1651470513.556336,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"releasing lock","identifier":"sd1.project.local"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"info","ts":1651470513.5574615,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"certificate obtained successfully","identifier":"sd2.project.local"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"info","ts":1651470513.557494,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"releasing lock","identifier":"sd2.project.local"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"warn","ts":1651470513.5588439,"logger":"pki.ca.local","msg":"installing root certificate (you might be prompted for password)","path":"storage:pki/authorities/local/root.crt"}
project-caddy-1        | 2022/05/02 05:48:33 define JAVA_HOME environment variable to use the Java trust
project-caddy-1        | 2022/05/02 05:48:33 not NSS security databases found
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"warn","ts":1651470513.561766,"logger":"tls","msg":"stapling OCSP","error":"no OCSP stapling for [sd1.project.local]: no OCSP server specified in certificate","identifiers":["sd1.project.local"]}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"warn","ts":1651470513.5634398,"logger":"tls","msg":"stapling OCSP","error":"no OCSP stapling for [sd2.project.local]: no OCSP server specified in certificate","identifiers":["sd2.project.local"]}
project-caddy-1        | 2022/05/02 05:48:33 certificate installed properly in linux trusts
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"info","ts":1651470513.5809436,"msg":"autosaved config (load with --resume flag)","file":"/config/caddy/autosave.json"}
project-caddy-1        | {"level":"info","ts":1651470513.580976,"msg":"serving initial configuration"}
```

My docker-compose is:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    project.local:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
#        ports:
#            - "${APP_PORT:-80}:80"
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            GITHUB_TOKEN: '${GITHUB_TOKEN}'
            FONTAWESOME_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN: '${FONTAWESOME_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - mailhog
    redis:
        build:
            context: "./Docker/Redis"
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        privileged: true
        command: sh -c "./init.sh"
        ports:
            - "${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379"
        volumes:
            - "sail-redis:/data"
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: "mailhog/mailhog:latest"
        ports:
            - "${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025"
            - "${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025"
        networks:
            - sail
    caddy:
        build:
            context: "./Docker/Caddy"
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: "${WWWGROUP}"
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "${APP_PORT:-80}:80"
            - "${APP_SSL_PORT:-443}:443"
        environment:
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            HOST_DOMAIN: project.local
        volumes:
            - "./Docker/Caddy/file:/etc/caddy"
            - ".:/srv:cache"
            - "./Docker/Caddy/certificates:/data/caddy/certificates/local"
            - "./Docker/Caddy/authorities:/data/caddy/pki/authorities/local"
            - "sailcaddy:/data:cache"
            - "sailcaddyconfig:/config:cache"
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - project.local
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-redis:
        driver: local
    sailcaddy:
        external: true
    sailcaddyconfig:
        driver: local
```

My `Caddifile` is:

```
{
    admin off
    # debug

    on_demand_tls {
        ask http://project.local/caddy
    }

    local_certs
    default_sni project
}

:80 {
    reverse_proxy project.local {
        header_up Host {host}
        header_up X-Real-IP {remote}
        header_up X-Forwarded-Host {host}
        header_up X-Forwarded-For {remote}
        header_up X-Forwarded-Port 443
        # header_up X-Forwarded-Proto {scheme}

        health_timeout 5s
    }
}

:443 {
    tls internal {
        on_demand
    }

    reverse_proxy project.local {
        header_up Host {host}
        header_up X-Real-IP {remote}
        header_up X-Forwarded-Host {host}
        header_up X-Forwarded-For {remote}
        header_up X-Forwarded-Port 443
        # header_up X-Forwarded-Proto {scheme}

        health_timeout 5s
    }
}

sd1.project.local {
    reverse_proxy project.local
}

sd2.project.local {
    reverse_proxy project.local
}
```

My `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM caddy:alpine

LABEL maintainer="Adrian Mejias"

ARG WWWGROUP

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apk add --no-cache bash \
    && apk add --no-cache nss-tools \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN addgroup -S $WWWGROUP
RUN adduser -G $WWWGROUP -u 1337 -S sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

My `start-container` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if [ ! -z "$WWWUSER" ]; then
    addgroup $WWWUSER sail
fi

if [ $# -gt 0 ];
then
    # @todo find alpine equivilent of below
    # exec gosu $WWWUSER "$@"
else
    /usr/bin/caddy run --config /etc/caddy/Caddyfile --adapter caddyfile
fi
```

Comment: I have the same issue following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68001757/3017716 . Any solutions? (I'm on Ubuntu)